# AppleIDAuthAgent: ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101

Tags: macos, authentication

What's the significance of this error?

It's showing up in the Console every 15 seconds:

```
error   11:24:07.727949 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101
error   11:24:22.836206 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101
error   11:24:37.943609 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101
error   11:24:53.058727 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101
```

Where the full log for AppleIDAuthAgent in the vicinity of one of these errors looks like this:

```
default 14:51:34.730204 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Checking account <private>
default 14:51:34.732439 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    _AppleIDAuthAccountForAppleID found account <private>
default 14:51:34.751103 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Reusing Account-cached GS token: AltDSID = <private>
default 14:51:34.773164 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    SERVER Doing account check for "XX...XX@????.???". (scheduledAccountCheckDispatcher()/AppleIDAuthd.cpp #545) accountCheckDispatch
default 14:51:34.773211 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Checking account <private>
default 14:51:34.774835 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    _AppleIDAuthAccountForAppleID falling back to account aliases
error   14:51:34.776461 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Request GS token for '<private>' start failed: -101
default 14:51:34.776534 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    ### Authenticate '<private>' failed: <private>
default 14:51:34.776624 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    SERVER Didn't succeed with .authenticate, and error is ERROR:"CSIdentityErrorDomain" #-101 kCSIdentityAppleIDInvalidAccountOrPasswordErr {  } so releasing session. (___Z31__AppleIDSessionDoCreateSessionPK10__CFStringS1_PK14__CFDictionaryPS1_PS4_PP9__CFError_block_invoke()/AppleIDXMLServerCommunications.cpp #902) queue.session.
default 14:51:34.776963 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Next action time for <private>: <private> (because the periodic certificate validation needs to occur)
default 14:51:34.777061 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Next time for '<private>': 2016-10-08 21:51:34 +0000 (497656294.777023 + 0.000000), -0.000001 seconds
default 14:51:34.777120 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Next time for '<private>': 2016-10-08 21:51:34 +0000 (497656294.777100 + 0.000000), -0.000001 seconds
default 14:51:34.777224 -0700   AppleIDAuthAgent    Next action time for <private>: <private> (because the account does not have a certificate nor an uploaded csr)
```

I don't know what this `'<private>'` is referring to. I'd love to clean this up because it's causing this really chatty and repetitive stuff in the logs.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having any problems with your Mac? (iCloud, email, other internet accounts)

Comment: Good question. I **am** having problems with the keyboard and trackpad freezing every few days, but neither I nor the Genius Bar folks can find a hardware problem to pin that on. And, that input device issue seems probably unrelated to this.

Comment: then why are you asking what these messages mean? Unless you're having a problem, don't look in the log. If you would like input on how to solve your keyboard/trackpad issues, you should create a new question.

Comment: @IronCraftMan - Because Apple is bothering to label this an *error* in the console logs.  If it's harmless then they'd call it a warning. If you don't want to help me, that's fine with me.